# How to do the inference on carla after training on Ray cluster?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ray, carla

I have trained a algorithm on Carla environment, using Ray cluster. I wanted to do the inference. May i know how i can do that, kindly help.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Assuming you used RLlib, you can use the `Agent`'s `export_policy_model` method to export the policy.